# ¿Cómo mostrar una ventana modal con datatables?

Tags: javascript, modal, datatable

Tengo el siguiente datatables y quiero que al hacer click sobre el botón mostrar, inmediatamente me aparezca una ventana modal con los datos de esa fila en unos inputs.

```js
var dataSet = [
    ["DMC-1","DOC-1","MTR-1","C_C1","DOC-1-SISTEMAS-CICLO_1",
    "COMPETENCIA 1 => Un est\u00e1ndar es un criterio claro y p\u00fablico \n\
    que permite juzgar si un estudiante, una instituci\u00f3n o el sistema educativo \n\
    en su conjunto, cumplen con unas expectativas comunes de calidad; expresa una situaci\u00f3n \n\
    deseada en cuanto a lo que se espera que todos los estudiantes aprendan."],
    ["DMC-2","DOC-2","MTR-2","C_C2","DOC-2-SISTEMAS-CICLO_2",
    "COMPETENCIA 2 => Un est\u00e1ndar es un criterio claro y p\u00fablico \n\
    que permite juzgar si un estudiante, una instituci\u00f3n o el sistema educativo \n\
    en su conjunto, cumplen con unas expectativas comunes de calidad; expresa una situaci\u00f3n \n\
    deseada en cuanto a lo que se espera que todos los estudiantes aprendan."]
];
        
$(document).ready(function() {
    listar();
} );    
             
    var listar = function(){
        var table = $("#example").DataTable({ 
            "data": dataSet,
            "paging": false,
            "columns": [
                { title: "ID"},
                { title: "ID_DOCENTE" },
                { title: "ID_MATERIA" },
                { title: "ID_CURSO" },
                { title: "REGISTRO" },
                { title: "COMPETENCIA" },
                {data: null,"defaultContent":"<button class='myBtn' id='myBtn'>MOSTRAR</button>" }
            ]
        });    
    mostrar_modal("#example tbody",table);
    };    
    
    function mostrar_modal(tbody, table){
        $(tbody).on("click", "#myBtn", function(){
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents("tr") ).data();
        var id_doc = $("#id_docente").val( data[1] ),
            id_mat = $("#id_materia").val( data[2] ),
            id_cur =  $("#id_curso").val( data[3] ),
            regist =  $("#registro").val( data[4] );
            $('#myModal').modal();
        //console.log( data );
        });        
    };  
    
//    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
//    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
//    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
//    btn.onclick = function() {
//        modal.style.display = "block";
//    };
//    span.onclick = function() {
//    modal.style.display = "none";
//    };
```

```css
           /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; 
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 20px; 
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        overflow: auto; 
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
        background-color: rgb(32,32,35);opacity:0.9;
    }
    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        background-color:blue;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #660033;
        width: 80%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color:#9ED929;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .modal-header {
        padding: 1px;
        background-color:#122b40;
        color: blue;
        height: 5%;
        border: 1px solid #660033;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>DATATABLES</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>   
    
    ID_DOCENTE:<input type="text" id="id_docente" /><br>
    ID_MATERIA:<input type="text" id="id_materia" /><br>
    ID_CURSO:<input type="text" id="id_curso" /><br>
    REGISTRO:<input type="text" id="registro" /><br>
    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <br><table id="example" width="100%" border="1"></table><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: revisa este ejemplo https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/modal.html

Comment: Revisa algunos errores que tienes, por ejemplo si la funcion se llama mostrar_modal la debes invocar con ese nombre no con mostar_modal. Y las funciones en mi caso prefiero iniciarlas como function mostrar_modal (tbody, table){}

Comment: Gracias corrregi y actualize mi codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilicé tu ejemplo y me comentas si te parece como quedo.

No olvides siempre importar las librerias. Ahorita deje que se ejecutara al inicio el modal, ya tu lo puedes modificar para que sea con un boton.

```js
var dataSet = [
    ["DMC-1","DOC-1","MTR-1","C_C1","DOC-1-SISTEMAS-CICLO_1",
    "COMPETENCIA 1 => Un est\u00e1ndar es un criterio claro y p\u00fablico \n\
    que permite juzgar si un estudiante, una instituci\u00f3n o el sistema educativo \n\
    en su conjunto, cumplen con unas expectativas comunes de calidad; expresa una situaci\u00f3n \n\
    deseada en cuanto a lo que se espera que todos los estudiantes aprendan."],
    ["DMC-2","DOC-2","MTR-2","C_C2","DOC-2-SISTEMAS-CICLO_2",
    "COMPETENCIA 2 => Un est\u00e1ndar es un criterio claro y p\u00fablico \n\
    que permite juzgar si un estudiante, una instituci\u00f3n o el sistema educativo \n\
    en su conjunto, cumplen con unas expectativas comunes de calidad; expresa una situaci\u00f3n \n\
    deseada en cuanto a lo que se espera que todos los estudiantes aprendan."]
];
      
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    listar();
    } );    
             
     function listar (){
        var table = $("#example").DataTable({ 
            "data": dataSet,
            "paging": false,
            "columns": [
                { title: "ID"},
                { title: "ID_DOCENTE" },
                { title: "ID_MATERIA" },
                { title: "ID_CURSO" },
                { title: "REGISTRO" },
                { title: "COMPETENCIA" },
                {data: null,"defaultContent":"<button class='myBtn'        id='myBtn'>MOSTRAR</button>" }
            ]
        });    
    mostrar_modal("#example tbody",table);
    }   
    
     function mostrar_modal(tbody, table){
     
        $(tbody).on("click", "#myBtn", function(){
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents("tr") ).data();
        var id_doc = $("#id_docente").val( "ID_DOCENTE" ),
            id_mat = $("#id_materia").val( "ID_MATERIA" ),
            id_cur =  $("#id_curso").val( "ID_CURSO" ),
            regist =  $("#registro").val( "REGISTRO" );
            $('#myModal').modal();
        console.log( data );
        });        
        
    }
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 35);
  opacity: 0.9;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #660033;
  width: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #9ED929;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #122b40;
  color: red;
  height: 5%;
  border: 1px solid #660033;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>DATATABLES</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
   
    <div id="myModal" class="modal >
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="close">&times;</span> ID_DOCENTE:

          <input type="text" id="id_docente" />
          <br> ID_MATERIA:
          <input type="text" id="id_materia" />
          <br> ID_CURSO:
          <input type="text" id="id_curso" />
          <br> REGISTRO:
          <input type="text" id="registro" />
          <br>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <table id="example" width="100%" border="1"></table>
    <br>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola [raintrooper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/58811/raintrooper), corregi el llamado a la funcion y realize el cambio en la funcion **mostrar_modal** y aparece ya la ventana modal, a traves de los botones **mostrar**, el problema que tengo ahora que en los inputs no toma los valores de la tabla, solo aparecen los titulos de la tabla, si me puedes ayudar en eso te lo agradezco.

Comment: Solo cambia desde donde se invoca el modal $('#myModal').modal(); a q sea después de asignar los valores a los input. Así el orden iría: click, asignar valores, mostrar modal.

Comment: Actualize mi codigo y ese es el orden que tengo, pero solo me pasa el valor de los titulos a los inputs al abrir la ventana modal con los botones de cada fila.

Comment: En la consola ves algún error?  Ya que no tengo pc a la mano para revisar ahorita.